# How to unparcel object where field is a subclass?

Tags: android, parcelable

I'm in a position where I have to implement Parcelable interface on a class that has a custom field that could be any subclass of Shape class:

```
class MyClass implements Parcelable
{
    Shape shape;
}
```

now, If I want to write the shape field to the parcel, it's very easy:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
{
    dest.writeParcelable(shape, flags);
}
```

And that's fine, because the Shape object could be any object that extends Shape and it will write correctly.

But when I read the object from parcel, I must pass a ClassLoader of the instance class, but at that point I don't know what the actual instance should be. for Shape it could be a Triangle,  Square, or a Circle.

```
    @Override
    public MyClass createFromParcel(Parcel source)
    {
        MyClass o = new Myclass();
        o.shape = source.readParcelable(Shape.class); // ???
        return o;
    }
```

My current workaround is to use Serializable to write this object, but this is very inefficient.
What would be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is OKAY to use `Shape.class` when you read your `Parcelable` as far as I know, since it will return an instance of the `SubClass`, which works fine **as long as** your sub classes of `Shape` implement the `Parcelable` method `writeToParcel()` on their own and also have their own `CREATOR` variables. The subclasses cannot rely on the `CREATOR` of `Shape`.

Comment: Thanks, only answer found considering this so far